# how to extract words from srt files & export to MS EXCEL

Tags: excel, subtitle, srt

I want to know frequencies of some words used in any particular TV Series.
if i can export words in SRT files to MS EXCEL then it'll be very easy.
thanks

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and describe the problems you have run into.  See the Help pages for how to ask a good question; and also how to provide an example that demonstrates your issues.

Answer (score 0):

To export srt (read textfiles) files to Excel you can use something like the following:

```
Sub m_srt_2_excel(str_fullname_srt As String)
Dim fso_active As FileSystemObject
Dim text_active As TextStream
Dim str_text As String
Dim var_data As Variant
Dim lng_count As Long

    Set fso_active = New FileSystemObject
    Set text_active = fso_active.OpenTextFile(str_fullname_srt, ForReading)
    str_text = text_active.ReadAll
    var_data = Split(str_text, vbCrLf)
    lng_count = UBound(var_data)

    selection.Resize(lng_count + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(var_data)

    Set text_active = Nothing
    Set fso_active = Nothing

End Sub
```

Or you can combine the OpenTextFile with the function to count the number occurrences:

```
Function f_count_string(str_text As String, str_find As String) As Long
Dim lng_len As Long

    lng_len = Len(str_text) - Len(Replace(str_text, str_find, vbNullString))
    f_count_string = lng_len / Len(str_find)
End Function
```